# How to execute python script with embedded python with arguments?

Tags: python, ios, objective-c, embedding

I've cross-compiled python and embedded it in my iOS app. I'm able to execute python script  as a string (`PyRun_SimpleString`) and import module and execute function with arguments (`PyImport_Import` and `PyObject_CallObject`) like in python embedding [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html).

But how can i execute python script file with arguments in command-line way:

```
file.py arg1 arg2
```

?

Comment: Would using `PySys_SetArgv` work?

Comment: it seems to be the right direction! How to run script using filename? Should i load module using `PyImport_Import` and do anything else after it?

Comment: Doing some digging I think this [accepted Answer on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142174/run-a-python-script-with-arguments) might provide you a good starting point.