# Running a file with arguments from python embedded within c

Tags: python, c, python-c-api

I'm currently working on a project that uses a C source file that has to interact with a python file (run the file and capture output) and im not exactly sure how to do it. currently the python file is run through terminal (linux) using:

```
python file arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4
```

and i am trying to embed python into the C code to just run the file first (no output capture) using the following code:

```
void python() {  
    FILE * file;
    int argc;
    char * argv[5];

    argc=5;
    argv[0]="pathtofile/file";
    argv[1]="arg1";
    argv[2]="arg2";
    argv[3]="arg3";
    argv[4]="arg4";
    Py_SetProgramName(argv[0]);
    Py_Initialize();
    PySys_SetArgv(argc,argv);
    file= fopen("pathtofile/file","r");
    PyRun_SimpleFile(file,"pathtofile/file");
    PyFinalize();   
}
```

args1-2 are hard coded, and args3-4 are determined by the C code (just determines integer values), this is then passed to the python file where it then executes.

When running the above code i get a:
 TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for + :NoneType and 'str'

Any advice from here on what could be my issue is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: 
I was using this as a guide as it seems to be similar to what im trying to acheive
[Run a python script with arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142174/run-a-python-script-with-arguments)

Comment: Your code is not even close to compiling!

Comment: Ok, `PyFinalize` -> `Py_Finalize` and then the problem apparently is in your **Python** code, thus you'd want to read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Your **`argc` is uninitialized** - did you compile with warnings enabled and warnings made into errors (`-Wall`, `-Werror` on GCC?); and your **`argv` is not properly null-terminated**. Thus your code has **undefined behaviour**. Anything might happen including [demons flying out of your nose](http://catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html). The argument to `fopen` `mode` must be a **string** yet you pass an `int` (character constant) - which has another UB.

Thus at least you **must** do:

```
int argc = 5;
char *argv[] = {
    "pathtofile/file",
    "arg1",
    "arg2",
    "arg3",
    "arg4",
    0 
};
input = fopen(..., "r"); //  "r", not 'r'!
```

Additionally you're not checking the return values of any of these functions. Any of them may fail and with Python you should expect them to fail - including your `fopen`! (Please tell that they're omitted for brevity).

Comment: thankyou for the quickly reply, i should of mentioned that i am very new to python so now that i have some direction i can try continue from here

Comment: Also relatively new to C, This was the first question i have asked so forgive me for not being as direct as i should have been.

Comment: You *can* and *should* give your question *minor edits* (not changing the thing you're asking, but fixing your question), including making sure the code is an actual copy-paste of your code (that one does not even compile **anywhere** because of the `:` after PyFinalize()`.

Comment: thanks i missed that when i made the first edit. i am unable to copy the code directly due to it being for a product so i rewrote it removing the confidential information.