# How do I run a python script and pass arguments to it in C

Tags: c

I have a python script `script.py` which takes command line params

I want to make a wrapper in C so I can call the `script.py` using `./script args`

So far I have this in my `script.c` file

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    system("python3.4 script.py");
    return 0;
}
```

How do I modify the script so I can do `./script arg1 arg2` and the C code executes `system("python3.4 script.py arg1 arg2");`

I don't have experience in C. Above code is from googling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `system()` is needlessly complicated in this case, as it effectively passes the given command string to (forked) `sh -c <command>`. This means that you'd have to handle possible quoting of arguments etc. when forming the command string:

```
 % sh -c 'ls asdf asdf' 
ls: cannot access 'asdf': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'asdf': No such file or directory
 % sh -c 'ls "asdf asdf"'
ls: cannot access 'asdf asdf': No such file or directory
```

Note the difference between the unquoted and quoted versions.

I'd suggest using `execve()`, if executing the python command is the only purpose of your C program, as the *exec* family of functions do not return on success. It takes an array of const pointers to char as the new *argv*, which makes handling arguments easier:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define PYTHON "/usr/bin/python3"
#define SCRIPT "script.py"

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    /* Reserve enough space for "python3", "script.py", argv[1..] copies
     * and a terminating NULL, 1 + 1 + (argc - 1) + 1 */
    int newargvsize = argc + 2;
    /* VLA could be used here as well. */
    char **newargv = malloc(newargvsize * sizeof(*newargv));
    char *newenv[] = { NULL };

    newargv[0] = PYTHON;
    newargv[1] = SCRIPT;
    /* execve requires a NULL terminated argv */
    newargv[newargvsize - 1] = NULL;
    /* Copy over argv[1..] */
    memcpy(&newargv[2], &argv[1], (argc - 1) * sizeof(*newargv));
    /* execve does not return on success */
    execve(PYTHON, newargv, newenv);
    perror("execve");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

As pointed out by others, you should use the [official APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142174/run-a-python-script-with-arguments) for this, if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate your command as a string. You just need to loop through argv[] to append each parameters given to the C program at then end of your command string. Then you can use your command string as the argument for the system() function.